# Como fazer para que esse código possa a ser usado mais de seis vezes

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
 <Title>Api de som</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="play()">play</button>

<Script>
let context = new AudioContext();
oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type="sine";
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.frequency.value=2000;

function play(){
oscillator.start(0);
oscillator.stop(0.5);
}
</Script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lendo o log de o erros está sendo informado:

> "message": "Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'start' on
> 'AudioScheduledSourceNode': cannot call start more than once."

Ou seja houve falha ao executar o método [`OscillatorNode.start()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode/start) pois o método não pode ser chamado mais de uma vez por [oscilador](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode).

Então migre para o corpo da função `play()` os métodos de criação e configuração da oscilador.

```js
function play() {
  let context = new AudioContext();
  oscillator = context.createOscillator();

  oscillator.type = "sine";
  oscillator.connect(context.destination);
  oscillator.frequency.value = 2000;

  oscillator.start(0);
  oscillator.stop(0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <Title>Api de som</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="play()">play</button>
</body>

</html>
```